# Can't embed youtube-dl in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, embed, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a Python Script that downloads videos from youtube, and to do this I'm trying to use youtube-dl. However, when I insert the code in my python script on their github page that is supposed to embed the code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

my terminal tells me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Youtube_dl'".
I have installed youtube_dl and upgraded it with "pip install youtube_dl" and "pip install --upgrade youtube_dl". Everything about youtube_dl should be installed but it keeps telling me I'm doing something wrong and that it cant find it. I have also tried to do "From YouTube_dl import *" instead of "import youtube_dl" and when I try to use "import youtube-dl" instead of "import youtube_dl" (because that is what it always says it downloads in cmd) it gives me a syntax error. any help apperceated.

Comment: Try running `pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl` and try again

Comment: It just tells me that the requirements are up to date, and doesn't fix the error, the file path it says it's installed in is C:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages if that is any indicator of anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Python module names are case-sensitive, and are all-lowercase by standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names). Going by your error message, it looks like you're trying to import `Youtube_dl` instead of `youtube_dl`, which will fail due to case-sensitivity.

Replace the import for YTDL in your code with the following, and your code should work:

```
import youtube_dl
```